# Check a number of form $a^b$.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Given a number $n$, what is best efficient way to check if it is of $a^b$ form for some $a,b\geqslant2$.
Provided $n$ can be as large as $10^{16}$.

Comment: Note that more efficient algorithms exist, but they are more complicated. For example http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers-ams.pdf

Comment: @fkraiem i cant download the paper right now because of internet problem.Could you provide me algorithm here?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that there are very few possible values for $b$ (only about $\log n$), so it is okay to just brute force through them. And then for each $b$ the array $[1^b, 2^b, 3^b, \dots, n^b]$ is sorted in ascending order, so we can do a binary search for a value in it which is equal to $n$. Using fast exponentiation, this gives an algorithm which runs in $O(\log^2n\log\log n)$ multiplications mod $n$.

I'll leave the actual (pseudo)code as an exercise, and it can also be found (along with a complexity analysis) in Dietzfelbinger, *Primality Testing in Polynomial Time* (LNCS 3000), as Algorithm 2.3.5.